# phonegap: when using android sdk 2.2, the listview of jquery mobile is scrolling slow

Tags: cordova

I using phonegap with jquery mobile. When using android sdk 2.2 (API Level 8), the listview of jquery mobile is scrolling slow. But it very smooth when I using android sdk 4.0 (API level 14)

I'm running it on my galaxy nexus, not virtual device

Comment: Try to run on real device. Then you see the difference....

Comment: Yes, that is the result on my galaxy nexus

Comment: For 2.2 which device you used?

Comment: both are running on my galaxy nexus

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.... It is obvious then.. Galaxy nexus is a Android 4.0 Phone so if you make use of sdk 4.0 then it uses the additional API's..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have make you app available on both Android < 4.0 and Android 4.0+ then you should compile 2 different apps.
The browser will underperform on Android 4.0+ if compiled for Android < 4.0.